Create file and then serve from disk after Apache request
When a file from an Apache server is requested, I want to have it created, saved on disk and then this created file be served, as if it already had been as file on the server. The clients will not be web browsers and can be very basic, the files can be quite large.
I tried to achieve this with PHP and Rewrite Rules and with mod_xsendfile. But X-SENDFILE does not add all the response headers to the file as a direct request would. Especially according to the documentation (https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) the "Content-Encoding" header is being dropped, so the files cannot be sent gzip encoded (if the client supports it) which is important since it reduces the file size a lot. But I also cannot create and serve .gz files, since the clients expect the files in a specific format.
I do not want to set redirects or a refresh header or the like since clients might not support this. I would like to have a solution that exactly works as if the file is simply downloaded from disk.
